# How can I get Sequence to implement Equatable?

Tags: swift, sequence, equatable

I have the following best attempt:

```
extension Equatable where Self: Sequence, Self.Element: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.elementsEqual(rhs)
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Furthermore, it requires both sequences to have the same exact type, whereas I only want to constraint that their `Element` types be the same. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Note that two sequences being equal doesn't imply `elementsEqual` – for example two equal `Set` values may contain the same elements but in different orders, which would case `elementsEqual` to return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocols never conform to other protocols. Protocols can *require* other protocols (which we typically call "protocol inheritance"), but this does not make protocols conform to other protocols. Protocols don't even conform to *themselves*, let alone something else. `Sequence.self` cannot be passed to things that require a `Sequence.Type`.

In any case, Equatable requires that the things being compared be of the same type. Other meanings of "equal" are not Equatable.

If you want to build methods on top of "these two sequences have the equal elements," that's fine. That's what `elementsEqual` does for you already. But that doesn't make them Equatable.

What algorithm are you trying to build that would use this and that `elementEqual` doesn't already handle?

It's possible what you're looking for is just some syntactic sugar to make it look like `==`. That's no problem at all. You can build any operator you want to implement `elementsEqual`.

```
infix operator ~=

func ~= <S1, S2>(lhs: S1, rhs: S2) -> Bool
    where S1: Sequence, S2:Sequence,
    S1.Element: Equatable, S1.Element == S2.Element
{
    return lhs.elementsEqual(rhs)
}
```

I usually recommend against custom operators, but if you are doing a lot of this kind of work, an explicit "these sequences have equal values in the same order" operator may be very useful. You just wouldn't want to use `==`, because that already means something that this doesn't mean. For example, two Sets may be `==`, but not `~=`, so you need to choose the tool you mean.

Comment: Slight nitpick: Some protocols conform to themselves, e.g `@objc` protocols without static requirements and, most recently, in Swift 5 `Error` conforms to itself (which is what allows for `Result<T, Error>`).

Comment: Determining if two sequences are equal is a pretty common problem if you work with lazy sequences, and converting them to arrays is non-performant. `elementsEqual` works, but is not as elegant

Comment: Not as elegant as what? If you mean `elementsEqual`, that's the correct tool. You can of course build additional tools on top of it to express more complex algorithms, but you can't express *Equatable*, because that has a specific meaning that this is not. If you said `set1 == set2`, do you expect that to execute the typical == code for Set, or do you expect it to run elementsEqual (if you created what you wanted)? They return different things.